# registering httpModules in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to register a custom HttpHandler in the web.config file. **[MSDN's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858(VS.71).aspx)** example shows an entry that is commented out...um which doesn't work so well.  When I uncomment I receive a `Could not load file or assembly 'HttpModule.cs' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` error.  The file name is HttpModule.cs and the class name is MyHttpModule.  There is no explicit namespace yet.

```
<httpModules>
     <add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyHttpModule, HttpModule" />
<httpModules>
```

I am sure I am overlooking the obvious.  Do I need to specify the file path somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am still learning much of the terminology and needed it spelled out for me.  In case any of you need the same...

As an example if:

- The base class name and project name is `TestSite`
- The namespace my class is in is `BusinessLogic`
- The class name is `PageAuthorization`

in the Web.config file...

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web> 
  <httpModules> 
   <add type= "BusinessLogic.PageAuthorization, TestSite" name="PageAuthorization" /> 
  </httpModules> 
 </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

In my case I had to mark my class with `IHttpModule`.  The definition of the class would look like:

```
public class PageAuthorization : IHttpModule
```

Comment: What to do if my module file in App_Code folder of web site ?

Answer (score 20):

If you are loading Custom module from .Net 4.0 GAC and IIS 6/7 classic mode  you have to use below code

```
 <system.web>
  <httpModules>
  <add name="ClientHttpModule" type="ClientServHttpModule.ClientHttpModule,ClientServHttpModule,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3af8d8e2f9e8b6c3" />
      </httpModules>
 </system.web>
```

ClientServHttpModule is namespace of your custom module.
Public key token you can get it from sn.exe app.

if you are running in Integrated mode.use below code

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="ClientHttpModule" type="ClientServHttpModule.ClientHttpModule,ClientServHttpModule,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3af8d8e2f9e8b6c3" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 16):

The `type` value is in the format of `{Class}, {assembly}`.

So in your case, it should be `MyHttpModule, MyDllName`

Where `MyDllName` is the name of the compiled DLL.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance in this, but do I need to explicitly compile the cs file into a dll in order to regsiter it in web.config?

Comment: It can be part of the web project, you just have to know the name of the compiled assembly.

Comment: How would I go about finding that, and then what would I enter as my regsitration?

Comment: The dll name is the assembly name, in the project properties for the project file.

Comment: FYI, just to be very explicit, I had to put `MyDLLName` WITHOUT the trailing `.dll`, ex. `MyDLLName.dll` didn't work.  This wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 6):

Note for people landing here looking for configuration for IIS 7 and above running in Integrated Mode:

```
<configuration> 
 <system.webServer> 
  <modules> 
   <add type= "BusinessLogic.PageAuthorization, TestSite" name="PageAuthorization" /> 
  </modules> 
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Rishi  I could use help with configuring system.webserver. If any of you guys can help please see my new post here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354083/web-config-system-webserver-errors

Answer (score 3):

To add to this, it is important to be sure that the .dll you are trying to use is in the project bin folder.  I had the problem of making my module in a separate project, but forgetting to push over the .dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I think HttpModules property in system.web is for ASP 3.5 or before. For ASP 4 or above use modules in system.webserver:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="TestModule"  type="WebApplication1.TestModule, WebApplication1"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```